# BottomAppBar sometimes sits on top of page content

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

I have a WP8.1 app with an overall pretty simple structure.  It has tons of binding statements and behaviors (interactivity) attached so I won't bother posting the whole thing, but here is the general idea is pseudo-XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <MapControl Grid.Row="0" />
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="300" />
</Grid>
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        ...AppBarButtons go here
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

This all works fine.  The map takes up most of the screen, search results (if any) are listed below.  But my app responds to ms-drive-to requests as well, and in that case I'm getting the requested address from the URI and adding it to the search results in OnNavigatedTo.  That's where the problem occurs.

When opening from a URI request, about one out of every four times, the bottom app bar sits on top of the page content instead of below it (see second screenshot, you can just barely make out the blue of the selected list item above the app bar).  If I do something that causes the screen to refresh (like opening a flyout with Placement="Full"), the problem disappears and the page renders normally.

This seems to me like a XAML bug but I can't think of a way around it.  I have tried processing the URI request in the page's and app bar's Loaded event (to make sure everything is drawn fully before manipulating the item source of the ListBox) but that doesn't work. I also tried moving the Page.BottomAppBar to the top of the layout, hoping it would get rendered first, but that didn't work either.

About the only thing that seems to work is to drastically reduce the complexity of the app bar, as in get rid of all bindings and behaviors and only have one icon that does nothing, that's obviously not workable, but seems to indicate that the app bar is taking too long to render itself and it's screwing up the page layout.  Any ideas?

[image: OK]
[image: Wrong]

**EDIT**: I eventually "fixed" this by removing a semi-complicated flyout from a command bar button and using a separate view instead. I guess the command bar was taking too long to init so the rest of the UI was beating it to the screen real estate.

Comment: My bad you are right. I looked at my map application and the order of the elements was `<.Resources/>` `<.ApplicationBar/>` `<BusyIndicator/>`; where the busy indicator contained the map and other controls.

Comment: In running my  WP8 app the appBar can cover lower presented controls when expanded; to which I believe is a design constant by the phone. The design we took was to allow the user to *slide* up the control away from the appbar (but I don't remember that being a bug per-se, it just didn't affect us as yours). So I would recommend to move the blue message to a different location on the screen.